# In PHPStorm, How to breakpoint in a method of a PHPUnit class?

Tags: php, debugging, phpunit, phpstorm

In PHPStorm, I want to debug a PHPUnit class. If I set a breakpoint in a method of the unit-testing class (the class that inherits from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`), whenever I run the test, PHPStorm executes the test, but never stops at the breakpoint, even though there are breakpoints in other places where it used to stop.

Is that a bug in PHPStorm ? how to stop in a `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`'s method ?

Comment: There is no difference at all. Maybe you are using "Run" instead of "Debug"? Otherwise -- please check path mappings (in case symbolic links are used or similar things).

Comment: That's the weird thing.. I use debug for sure. I *am* inclined towards path issues: I can't figure out what are these "bootstrap file", "skeleton generator" and "phpunit-skelgen", and don't understand how they are related and what they are good for ?

Comment: You can find what it is and how it can be used here: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html

Comment: I am having the same problem using PHPStorm 8

Comment: Just FYI: I disabled the "listen to debug connections" button and it started to stop at the breakpoints as normal.

Answer (score 11):

in order PHPStorm to stop at the breakpoint within tests you must "Debug" (Shift + F9) but not "Run" (Shift + F10) your configuration.

Comment: As I said, I do use "debug". It does stop, but only in methods of classes not inherit from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

Answer (score 8):

If your test case has the @runInSeparateProcess comment or in the phpuint.xml configuration file the `<phpunit processIsolation="true">` tag has the processIsolation attribute and the value of it is true than debugger will not stop on the breakpoint because it is running in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the file you place the breakpoint in is actually the file that is getting executed. You might have multiple versions of PHPUnit installed.

Alternatively override the Testcase inside your own tests folder and extend from it. Create a function with the same name and parameters you want to place the breakpoint in there. Then just wire-up the call to the parent:

```
class My_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function funcToTest($param) {
        return parent::funcToTest($param);
    }
}
```

Then make your test extends from that testcase class instead and place the breakpoint in there. When you hit it, you can step into further deep to actually find out which concrete file from phpunit is used and where it is placed on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find if you have the correct PHP interpreter which has the Xdebug installed. I had similar issue and the reason of no breakpoint was cause of several interpreter configured in PHPStorm and the correct one which has Xdebug was not selected. You can change the interpreter by editing the `PHPStorm Settings > Languages and Frameworks > PHP`